# QGIS server: "API not found error: collection was not found" when reaching the /collections endpoint of the OGC API - Features specification

Tags: postgis, qgis-server, ogc-api, ogc-api-features

I am trying to set up a QGIS project (`my_project.qgs`) to server data using the [OGC API - Features](https://www.ogc.org/standards/ogcapi-features), protocol. For this purpose, I'm using this [Docker image.](https://hub.docker.com/layers/camptocamp/qgis-server/latest/images/sha256-ab74360fc26ab11eff14a21318a776a5ac72fff7e8b3f4d9f22172a1a597f147?context=explore).

When trying to access my file in a web browser using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/wfs3/collections/my_layer_in_qgis?MAP=/etc/qgisserver/my_project.qgs
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/wfs3/collections?MAP=/etc/qgisserver/my_project.qgs
```

which is also the URL reached when clicking on the "Feature collections" item on the landing page available at this URL `http://localhost:8080/wfs3?MAP=/etc/qgisserver/my_project.qgs`:

[image: Feature collection item on the landing page]

this `404` response is sent back:

```
[{"code":"API not found error","description":"Collection was not found"}]
```

which seems to be thrown by line 244 here: https://qgis.org/api/qgsserverogcapihandler_8cpp_source.html

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the way I call the feature collection? Or did I miss something in the [QGIS server WFS-3 documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/services.html#wfs3-ogc-api-features)?

My .qgs file is a simple project with a single layer in a single group. The layer is a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) layer based on a single table having a single feature (row) with a geometry in EPSG:2056 and two other attributes, a name and an id. The service is simply setup as follow:

[image: WFS setup in the QGIS project file]

I can properly access the layer using WMS (which is also configured).

The .qgs project file was created using QGIS `3.14.1-Pi`

Comment: How do you run your docker? Can you provide the command?